# nexus n3k %ACLQOS-SLOT1-4-ACLQOS_OVER_THRESHOLD alert

Tags: nx-os

I have a n3k-c3064pq-10gx and when i execute show loggin it shows the following error :

```
%ACLQOS-SLOT1-4-ACLQOS_OVER_THRESHOLD: Inst 0 Tcam 8 Bank 1's ((null)) usage has reached its threshol
d
```

i have 3x acl and 2x route-map and and with my 3x acl ijust i have some permit IP x x nothing more,
any idea?
thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Cisco Documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/system_messages/reference/sl_nxos_book/sl_3k.html), this warning is informing you that you are maxing the TCAM resource allocation for a specific feature. You should be able to see your utilisation/allocation per feature via:

`show system internal access-list resource utilization`

You may also be able to perform [TCAM carving](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/security/7x/b_Cisco_n3k_Security_Config_7x/b_Cisco_n3k_Security_Config_7x_chapter_0111.html) to reallocate resources if required.

Comment: the only thing is near the threshold is "N3K SUP                                 125     3       97.65" other things has at leat %70 free space

Comment: @Blackmetal, that means you need to change the allocation of your TCAM, reducing the TCAM allocated to the things with little usage, and giving more to what is full.

Comment: i can not find which tcam module should i adjust, because everything seems right, can you guide me more?